# AngularJs service not injected in controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services, angularjs-digest

I am having trouble with something very simple like inject a basic service into a controller and despite reading documentation and other SO question i really don't see the mistake i'm making.

Here's my simplified code:

```
angular.module ('travelApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute'])
```

//CONTROLLERS

```
.controller('searchController', ['$scope','myParams', function ($scope,ngRoute,myParams){

   $scope.place = myParams.place;
   $scope.$watch('place', function(){
      myParams.place = $scope.place;
    });

    $scope.bind = function(){
        console.log(myParams.getPlace);
    };
}])
```

//SERVICES

```
.service('myParams', function(){
    this.place = 'start';
});
```

//MY HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-app="travelApp">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="searchPage" ng-controller="place">
    <div>
        <h3>Start Here</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBar" ng-model="place">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="bind()">bind data</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a number of things in the past few hours but keep getting the

"TypeError: Cannot set property 'place' of undefined"

It seems the service is just no available inside the controller, i don't know if it has something to do with routing but i doubt so.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bb3AHsoAQcaBLUcFAqU4)

Answer (score 2):

Your dependencies must match if you use array syntax. Remove `ngRoute` from the controller's arguments.

```
.controller('searchController', ['$scope','myParams', function ($scope, myParams){
```

Comment: Thanks, i updeted the code, still not working for me.

Comment: Your plunker's external links were incorrect. It works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6asYb5l7U2H8KTrmNtnX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks again, now interpolation works fine but my real intent is to update the service parameter so that i can pass the to other controller. It still trows an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'place' of undefined"

Comment: Please post that issue as a new question and I'd be happy to help out.

Comment: I appreciate your help Anid, this is my original question "AngularJs service not injected in controller", the interpolation was just a test. When i try this code in a browser using developer tools is telling me that the "place" is undefined although it should be available as the service is referenced correctly.

Comment: The code in your question and your Plunker are really inconsistent. Your plunker's code gives that error because you have `myParams` declared as an argument to `bind` when nothing is actually being passed in. `getPlace` is also not a member of your service, so I'm not sure what your intent is.

Comment: Working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/Iew8Qz5BS1IgS3m2GxWL?p=preview All I did was remove `myParams` from `bind`'s arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the error. now it's working correctly. I didn't know that functions inside controller have access to service parameters. On top of thta i was calling bind() without passing any argument.